# Replace customized BBCode-style opening code tags with html tags and a dynamic class name

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to replace some words using regular expression.

My words

```
[code-html(or css,js)]
```

html is variable.
I want to replace like this

```
<pre><code class="language-html(or css,js)">
```

How can I replace all variable using regular expression?

I can replace just one case.

```
preg_match_all("/\[code-([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\]/", "<pre><code class=\"([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\]\">", $matches);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple solution that will require that your opening code tags have the language substring and capture it for reuse in the replacement string.

Here are three basic cases...

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/WR7v0))

```
$inputs = [
    '[code-html]',
    '[code-css]',
    '[code-js]',
];

var_export(
    preg_replace(
        '~\[code-(html|css|js)]~',
        '<pre><code class="language-$1">',
        $inputs
    )
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => '<pre><code class="language-html">',
  1 => '<pre><code class="language-css">',
  2 => '<pre><code class="language-js">',
)
```